# How do I do dictionary definitions of class attributes?

Tags: c#

I've got a class like so:

```
public class book
{
    public string Author {get; set;}
    public string Genre  {get; set;}
}
```

Now, `Genre`, for instance, is supposed to be a `Dictionary`, with a list of different Genres with an ID, so when I create a new Book, I set the `Genre` as one of the `Dictionary` items.

How would I set this up? Would I have a separate `Genre` class where I define each one, or... I guess I'm just not sure how to approach it.

Comment: So you want a **dictionary** of genres? That's a bit of an odd setup.

Comment: I mean I'm just using an example to explain it, but the requirements are that I need a dictionary for several of the attributes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a `Genre` class would be the best way to set it up.

```
 public class Book
    {
        public string Author {get; set;}
        public Genre Genre  {get; set;}
    }

    public class Genre
    {
        public string Id {get; set;}
        public string Name  {get; set;}
    }
```

But, if by "dictionary" you literally mean `Dictionary`, then

```
public class Book
{
    public string Author {get; set;}
    public Dictionary<int, string> Genre  {get; set;}
}
```

Comment: So is there no reason then to use the dictionary class built into C#? I guess that's what I'm confused about.

Comment: The second part is what looks right, but do I define the dictionary items in another class or something? How do I populate the dictionary? Sorry, it just doesn't really make sense to me.

Comment: `Genre.Add(1, "Horror");` -- `Genre.Add(2, "Kung-Fu");`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like this?

```
public class Book
{
  public string Author { get; set; }
  public Genre Genre { get; set; }

  public Book(string author, Genre genre)
  {
    Author = author;
    Genre = genre;
  }
}

public class Genre 
{
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public static ICollection<Genre> List = new List<Genre>();

  public Genre(string name)
  {
    Name = name;

    List.Add(this);
  }
}
```